# Circuitkz with relative +(x,y) coordinates updates current pen position

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? When using pure TIKZ everything works as expected:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- ++(2,0) -- +(0,-1) +(0,0) -- +(2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: TIKZ with relative coordinates working correctly]

But when doing the same with CircuiTIKZ, the y coordinate seems to be updated:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) to[short] ++(2,0) to[C] +(0,-1) +(0,0) to[short] +(2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: CircuiTIKZ fails with relative coordinates]

Comment: My first example also works as I expect when substituting `--` with `to`. What does adding attributes to `to` changes? Also `\draw (0,0) to +(4,0) ++(2,0) to[C] +(0,-1);` seems to produce wrong results, as `+(0,-1)` ends up at (0,-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is very simple.

After the first part of the path, `(0,0) -- ++(2,0)` (which is common), in the first case you use `-- +(0,-1)` in the second you add a capacity. The capacity symbol shifts the current position of the pen, something that your syntax `-- +(0,-1)` does not. Actually, you will perceive the same behaviour if you were using:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,-1) +(0,0) -- +(2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) to[short] ++(2,0) to[C] +(0,-1) +(0,0) to[short] +(2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

because `-- ++(0,-1)` shifts the position as well:

[image]

Now, having this in mind, you may want to do the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- ++(2,0) -- +(0,-1) +(0,0) -- +(2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) to[short] ++(2,0) to[C] +(0,-1) +(0,1) to[short] +(2,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

so you will get:

[image]

Comment: But `\draw (0,0) to +(4,0) ++(2,0) to +(0,-1);` the first `to` seems not to update the pen to (4,0). Because the second line ends up at (0,-1). I haven't wrapped my head arround the arcane doings of `to`. Thanks for your nicely illustrated answer!

Comment: Correct answer: `\draw (0,0) to ++(4,0) --(2,0) to +(0,-1);`. Try to learn why it is correct: the pgfmanual has a very detailed explanation on all combinations of `-- +`, `-- ++` etc..

Comment: But `--(2,0)`(draw line to point (2,0)) introduces an absolute coordinate and thus explicitly move to the point (2,0). This would break, if I'd changed the first moveto (0,0) to something different. So you probably meant `++(-2,0)`?

Comment: Indeed, you're right. The point I was trying to highlight in my previous message is the difference between `+` and `++` operators.